# How can I use _slug inside another _slug directory in dynamic nuxt.js routing?

Tags: routes, nuxtjs, dynamic-routing

My folder structure

[image]

> Showing this wanning on my console.

```
Duplicate param keys in route with path: "/design/:slug?/:slug"
```

Comment: you cannot use same name for more than 1 param, you are free to use any other name for it, maybe `slug2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good to see your problem was solved,
to be more specific: you can use any name for params (it's not limited to slug or anything).

You cannot use same name for multiple params in same routing.

**You Can't**

```
design/_slug/_slug
design/_info/_info
```

**You Can**

```
design/_slug/_info
design/_slug/_slug2

*or whatever you want to name it
```

bear in mind this limits are for params inside a route scope, meaning you cannot use duplicate param inside a scope, you are free to use same name under another route, like `product/_slug` alongside `design/_slug` is fine.

Comment: despite the warning, there seems to be no technical restrictions, as it is working in my case.

Answer (score 0):

So just change the folder name. _slug to _slug2 .
Different name for slug.

[image]